# Cannot open xml file

Tags: php, xml, ms-word, phpword

I'm using `phpword` library to print data from database by using template. I 
realized that `phpword` does not replace any of the keywords with my input so I 
searched what causing it and found that word generates arbitrary tags around my keywords so `phpword` fails to find my keys.

Then I changed my template's format from `.docx` to `zip` to open `document.xml` file to erase unnecessary tags around my keyword but I cannot open `document.xml`, it says there is an error in row 2 but whole `XML` file is in row 2 so it is impossible to find where is the error.

Some suggested that use `notepad++` and `xmlplugin` to regenerate `XML` file with proper line breaks. I did it but error still shows the same row and I can't find the error, also I used online tools to check whether there is an error or not in my `document.xml` but those tools says your `XML` file is fine, sorry for the long explanation, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please break up your question into paragraphs for easier reading and provide any relevant code or links to libraries involved.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure what to upload as code so I explained the process, I guess its not about my template but word causes this problem

Comment: Having the line of code that triggers the error and the full error itself would be a good starting point

Comment: It says
"The open XML file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents"
row 2 column 1069 - Unspecified error

Comment: add the full error you just mentioned and the original code that triggers it. Also, Column 1069 refers to the point in the line of text where the issue is triggered, so take a look at what is at 1069 (don't paste into question. provide a link to pastebin or similar if needed).

Comment: Oh its too messy :), I guess I'll search for another solution, thank you for you help